# Find and Replace formula and function needed In an Excelsheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have tow Excel Sheet. First Sheet is Keywords and Second sheet is Original Text. keywords text is 6,000 and original text is 3,00,000. When I write VBA function, this function is not work. When I write Proper Formula it is work properly. But few keywords is upper case.

original text:

```
Bmw 325 / 328 Series / M3 L6 2.5/3.2L P/A M/T radiator
Nissan Maxima Radiator & condenser Cooling Fan assembly Tyc
Gmc, Chevy Truck Tail Light W/Connector plate Passenger Side
```

keywords text:

```
BMW
Radiator
Assembly
GMC
Plate
condenser
```

I need to result output:

```
**BMW** 325 / 328 Series / M3 L6 2.5/3.2L P/A M/T **Radiator**
Nissan Maxima Radiator & **Condenser** Cooling Fan **Assembly** Tyc
**GMC**, Chevy Truck Tail Light W/Connector **Plate** Passenger Side
```

I don't understand how can I solve this type problem. I need to solution quickly.

Comment: Might be useful to post what you already tried, and what the problems were with each approach.

Comment: Look that first result "**BMW** 325 / 328 Series / M3 L6 2.5/3.2L P/A M/T **Radiator**" this a one sentence. I need Bmw=BMW, radiator=Rediator it is one sentence. I have six thousands keywords and original text is 30K.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
Sub ReplaceWords()
  Dim myarray As Variant
  myarray = Array("BMW", "Radiator", "Assembly", "GMC", "Plate", "Condenser")
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = Range("A1")
  For Each element In myarray
   r.Replace What:=element, Replacement:="**" & element & "**", MatchCase:=False
  Next
End Sub
```